# Slow Ember-CLI Build times?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, ember.js, ember-cli

I recently updated my project to Ember-CLI 0.0.46 and I'm noticing considerable slowdowns in my project builds...

```
Build successful - 259366ms.

 Slowest Trees                  | Total
-------------------------------+----------------
TreeMerger (ExternalTree)      | 77565ms
CompassCompiler                | 43122ms
TreeMerger                     | 38668ms
TreeMerger (stylesAndVendor)   | 36651ms
TreeMerger (appAndDependencies) | 20901ms
```

This seems CRAZY. Granted, I am using Bootstrap, but still, it was NOT this bad until recently. The only other component I've added is oauth2 support.

There was some talk (on Github I believe) of adding a view in the build that showed how many total files were touched. What became of that?

Thanks for any insights.

Comment: what platform are you on? For Windows, there's this set of tips here: http://www.ember-cli.com/#solving-performance-issues-on-windows

Comment: But the reported times _are_ crazy. I have never had a build slower than 15s (initial) / 10s (incremental). These times have been halved in ember 0.1.1, for me.

Comment: Sorry for the delay in responding. I was on vacation, away from connectivity. I'm on OS X 10.10. Going to try updating to latest Ember, CLI, etc. that's come out since I've been away and see how that goes.

Comment: 0.1+ should do a lot of nice things in that regard. AFAIK broccoli fixed a lot of performance related issues. They're all in the current ember-cli.

Comment: You aren't using vagrant are you? or some sort of file share?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ember-cli project has since vastly improved the performance of the build pipeline. If I remember correctly there was also a bug in an older version regarding tmp files that worsened the performance which might be the cause.

My recommendation would be to update to the latest available version.